# practical example for plot position(x y z) of fixed frames(end-effector) in rqt

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

hi . i want plot position and  velocity of end effector that have fixed joint  using rqt.
How to plot position(x y z) and velocity of fixed frames(end-effector) in rqt ??
i searched and searched but couldn't find any example for  plot position(x y z) of fixed frames(end-effector) in rqt .
in matlab we can plot like this :
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15339/practical-example-for--plot-position(x-y-z)-of-fixed-frames(end-effector)-in-rqt/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2997/zakizadeh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You'll have more luck asking this at ROS Answers, this forum is for Gazebo-related questions.

http://answers.ros.org

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1